# Forcing serial port release from pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

When my application crashes, some of the serial ports apparently remain locked and I have no choice but to reboot the Raspberry Pi.

I was wondering if there is a way to ensure that, before crashing, the ports are released. Another alternative would be to create a function that forces the release of a certain port when my code starts.

Is there such a thing within `pyserial`, or another Python library?

Comment: There are several ways, like properly handling exceptions or using a context manager. You'll need to show some code if you want to get proper answers

Answer (score 1):

You have the command `top` to list all applications that are running.

You can retrieve your PID of the instance of your application and terminate it with the command `kill -9 YOUR_PID`.

Killing the app will free your serial port.

Else you can open your serial port with `exclusive` to `False`: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial

> A port cannot be opened in exclusive access mode if it is already open in exclusive access mode.

Comment: The default when creating a serial port is `exclusive=None`. Looking at the source code (`serialposix.py`) , getting a lock is only attempted when `exclusive=True`.

Comment: Ok, what if you set it to false?

Comment: Basically, it calls `fcntl.flock(self.fd, fcntl.LOCK_UN)`, to try and unlock the port.